# Difference between "regular" convolution and circular convolution.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution

In my class of functional analysis we've defined two types of convolutions:

1. Suppose $f,g: K \to \mathbb C$ are Riemann integrable functions with compact support in $K \subseteq \mathbb R$, then the **convolution** $f * g$ is defined as $$ (f * g)(x) = \int_Kf(y)g(x-y)dy$$
2. Suppose $f,g: \mathbb T \to \mathbb C$ (with $\mathbb T$ the unit circle in $\mathbb C$ equipped with the metric defined as the shortest arc between two points in it) are Riemann integrable functions (in the sense they are integrable as periodic functions over $[-\pi, \pi]$), then their **circular convolution** is defined as $$ (f * g)(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)g(x-y)dy$$

We did say in class that we can identify the space of functions defined on $\mathbb T$ with the periodic functions over $[-\pi,\pi]$, but it seems to me that the two definitions are basically the same (except we normalize the integral in the circular case).
So is there a difference?

Comment: The choice of normalisation on the convolution does not change its fundamental properties, the one difference is which constants appear in which relations, just like for the choice of normalisation for the $L^2$ norm of periodic functions or the choice of normalisation for a Fourier transform. You do have to be careful since different authors use different conventions even in the same field of maths though.